A tenant is going through a section 21 eviction and is now awaiting a bailiff letter
A tenant is going through a section 21 no fault eviction.
The tenant never missed the rent or caused problems.
Some time has passed since the order for possession date and the tenant is waiting for a letter from the bailiffs to give notice of when they will come.
Do the bailiffs use Royal Mail to deliver or do they hand deliver?
The Royal Mail are extremely slow and unreliable so I was wondering if they post it and it gets lost, what happens then? The Royal Mail only deliver once or twice a week in the tenant's area, and they use temps all the time. In the past the tenant has had things go missing or delayed by a couple of weeks and recently had a 'special delivery' go missing, so the tenant has no confidence in them at all.
The tenant tried phoning HM Courts and Tribunals Service, but couldn't get to speak to anyone about this.

What makes you think the bailiffs will send a letter? If the court has ordered possession the bailiffs can turn up whenever they next have slot in their no-doubt busy schedule.  (this was the case about 10 years ago anyway - I know from bitter experience.)

Questions asking for legal advice are off-topic here so I've edited it to try to make it generic.

Apocryphal: I once returned home on a Friday to find a bailiff's notice pinned to the door – they would return at some time over the weekend and sieze property. They had the wrong house, and it trapped me at home for the weekend. Of course they did not return.

Two different legal advisers at Shelter told me that bailiffs should give you at least two weeks notice of eviction, and even their website states: "A notice giving the time and date of the eviction must be delivered by Enforcement Agents (known as bailiffs) to the premises 14 days before the eviction date"

"I was wondering if they post it and it gets lost, what happens then?"
Section 7 of the Interpretation Act 1978 provides:

Where an Act authorises or requires any document to be served by post
(whether the expression “serve” or the expression “give” or “send” or
any other expression is used) then, unless the contrary intention
appears, the service is deemed to be effected by properly addressing,
pre-paying and posting a letter containing the document and, unless
the contrary is proved, to have been effected at the time at which the
letter would be delivered in the ordinary course of post.

This means that in cases where bailiffs are required to give notice, are permitted or required by law to do so by post, and have validly posted it to you, there is a presumption that you have received it whenever the post would ordinarily arrive. It's very easy for someone to say they didn't receive something and this rule exists to avoid the courts being flooded with such arguments.
Presumptions can be rebutted but the burden of proof shifts to you to prove that you didn't receive it. This will usually be quite difficult. It could be possible if for example there was a postal strike, or you have evidence that your local postman has been dumping letters in the woods, or you have a CCTV camera pointed towards your letterbox.
More to the point, the tenant knows there's a possession order out there. Unless they intend to appeal it, they are going to have to leave the property sooner or later. The best course of action is to assume the bailiff will arrive soon and to prepare accordingly.
